# Doctrine: Could not create database for connection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm currently working on a website using Symfony2 and doctrine2 for the database. I did everything from this tutorial:http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/doctrine-2-the-blog-model.html

However, when I try to do this:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

I get this error:

```
Could not create database for connection named `CHuts_DB`
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'rootDB'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

And this is my parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: '3396'
    database_name: CHuts_DB
    database_user: rootDB
    database_password: ***
    ...
    database_path: null
```

I don't understand why it's not working. I'm fairly new to Symfony2 and I've searched a bit on internet but I couldn't find someone with the same error message as me.

Comment: Check permissions for `rootDB` user. Can this user create databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHPMyAdmin go to:

```
Users -> rootDB -> Structure (check CREATE)
```

and save privileges of user.

Answer (score 1):

I think your user and/or password aren't correct.

You can try mysql command line:

```
> mysql -u rootDB -p
```

or install [adminer.php](http://adminer.org) in your webserver and try to verify the account.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me on Mac OS X with MAMP (or MAMP Pro).

Add **database.unix_socket** in **app/config/parameters.xml**

```
parameters:
    database.driver:        pdo_mysql
    database.host:          localhost
    database.port:          8888
    database.name:          my-database-name
    database.user:          root
    database.password:      root
    database.unix_socket:   /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Add **unix_socket** in **app/config/config.xml**

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # ...
        unix_socket: "%database.unix_socket%"
```